# AngularJS load first item's details on list

Tags: list, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a list view that allows me to click on and display its details:

```
<li ng-repeat="item in data.items" ng-click="show(item.id)" ng-class="{'active':selectedId==item.id}">
  <div class="item-list">.. </div>
...
</li>
```

I am using ng-show and ng-hide to bascially show details when i click on the item, or hide if there's no items in the list.

I would like to find out how can I conditionally display the first item's details on the list on page load. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use the $first boolean of the ngRepeat directive like this:

```
<div ng-show="$first">Details</div>
```

Full example with the following data given:

```
{items:[item:{id:01, name:item1, price:1}, item:{id:02, name:item2, price:2}]}
```

And the HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li ng-repeat="item in data.items" ng-click="show(item.id)" ng-class="{'active':selectedId==item.id}">
      {{item.id}} <span ng-show="$first">{{item.name}} - {{item.price}}</span>
    </li>
</ul>
```

Gives the following output:

```
<ul>
    <li>01 <span>item1 - price1</span></li>
    <li>02 </li>
    <li>03 </li>
</ul>
```

Obviously the outputted elements are a few more, but this is done for clarity.

Comment: Hi Bjarke, is $first going to get the first item.id ? what is the format like to get that particular element in the array? What i meant is something like item.id[0]. Thank you!

Comment: Could you explain a bit more about what data.items contain? Because I'm a little confused about what you are iterating over.

Comment: data.items structure is something like 
items {
item {id:01, name:item1, price:1}, 
item {id:02, name:item2, price:2}
}

Comment: Thanks Bjarke, your explanation is very clear! Appreciate your quick reply!